# If a company edits my files through Google API, will it show as my name or the API's name in version history?

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive-api, google-oauth, content-security-policy

I gave google drive access to a company through Google API because I needed to upload a file for them to edit and review. It is a writing editing company.  If I give them Google Drive access and {if they edit my files directly on Google Drive, which I don't want since I want them to edit on the file I uploaded], in google docs version history, will it appear as my name or appear as the API's name?

In this case, the writing editing company can just claim ALL MY WORK as them hence they had access and can just say that they done everything under my name since they had Google Drive API access. Can someone explain how this works? And this happened months ago and Google only shows security history 28 days prior. Someone please help ease the worry. It is a personal gmail not gsuite

I tried downloading Google Takeout and I don't seem to see the permission history and the security history of my account with third party apps. Is there anyway to verify this or find third party app access history?

Comment: This question is a better fit for [security.se].